# How to measure chord on a rounded trailing edge airfoil?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

So, should I measure it by the rearmost point (in contact with the tangent line) or the point coinciding with the end of the camber line (represented by the line starting at the circumference center)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's probably easier to draw the camber line first.

Answer (score 2):

The [chord](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(aeronautics)) line is drawn as a straight line between the ends of the [camber](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camber_(aeronautics)) line.  Interestingly, with extreme [camber](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(aeronautics)), this may not be the tip of the leading and trailing edges of the airfoil.

The camber line is equidistant from the top and bottom of the wing. On a rounded tip, it would start at the equal bisection of the semicircle, just as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, does it matter?

You probably need a chord so you can non-dimensionalize data.  In that case, just be consistent -- use the same chord when you re-dimensionalize and it doesn't really matter what you choose.

This is why it is always important to communicate Sref and cbar with aerodynamic coefficient data.

If the airfoil without the rounded TE was 'known', then I would use the chord based on that original definition.

I.e. if the TE was blunt -- or thickened and then rounded, then the chord endpoint would be the center of the circle (marked by the x).

However, if the TE was truncated and then rounded, then the chord endpoint would likely be at some extrapolated point outside of the zoomed-in view.

Comment: I have an airfoil with a sharp trailing edge, but I had to thicken it by 3mm to comply with SAE rules and add roundness to the end. Now, I need to resize the airfoil back to its original chord length, but I'm not sure which point to use as a reference to the trailing edge. These images are of the airfoil with the rounded edge.

The chord length is important because I need the exact value to obtain the typical Reynolds number used in FSAE competitions.

Comment: So, what spot should i use as chord endpoint?

Comment: It won't matter.  What %chord is that 3mm?  If your Reynolds number is 500,000, will anything really be different if it is 505,000 instead?

If you were doing a more sophisticated calculation of the boundary layer, the actual Reynolds number on the wetted surface (which will be different for the top/bottom surface) would be more important than the Re based on chord -- and the wetted length is longer than the TE extension.  Why do you need to re-size the airfoil back to the original chord length?  Who is dictating this definition of chord within 1% ?

Comment: If you are worried about breaking some rule -- having too large a wing -- as measured by chord and span -- and therefore failing the pre-race inspection.  Then you need to look at the FSAE rules and find out how they actually measure the chord.  do they use a giant caliper?  Do they use a ruler?  Do they ask the team what the chord is?

I you understand exactly how it will be measured by the judges, then you should make sure your CAD model meets that -- with some room for margin (paint, stickers, etc).